# Unable to set a property after its animation in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I used this code to animation my window:

```
winLogin login = new winLogin();
login.Owner = this;
login.Show();

DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.From = 0;
da.To = this.Left + ((this.Width - login.Width) / 2);
da.AutoReverse = false;
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
login.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, da);
```

Problem is that whenever i set the `Left` property of this window(after the animation), it goes crazy.

I used this code to align the child windows to be always on the center but the `Left` property of the windows on which i used an animation cannot be properly changed.

```
private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (Window win in this.OwnedWindows)
        {
            win.Top = this.Top + ((this.Height - win.Height) / 2);
            win.Left = this.Left + ((this.Width - win.Width) / 2); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, when you set an animation you should always remove the potential previous animation of that property:

```
login.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, null);
login.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, da);
```

If you don't so this you will get a memory leak and probably some other undesired behavior.

Also due to the [DependencyProperty precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) you can not set a value on a DependecyProperty that has an active animation, wich is the case in your animation because its [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) is set to `HoldEnd` (the default). Again you would have to remove the animation first.

Comment: Actually wouldn't it be alright to set the value with SetCurrentValue? NVM, of course the animation will still have precedence with HoldEnd.

Comment: The new .NET 4 DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue is used to set the value on databound DependencyProperties without affecting the databound source value. Your Window.LeftProperty however is not databound. Animations set the property directly.