# How to remove animation after it's completed

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'd like to remove the animation from my target property because i'm [Unable to set the property after its animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733760/unable-to-set-a-property-after-its-animation-in-wpf).

So, according to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3733898/3970387) of the question above, I've to remove the animation after it's completed. But **how to do it** ?

Here's my code:

```
public class GridLengthAnimation : AnimationTimeline {

    static GridLengthAnimation() {
        FromProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof(GridLength), typeof(GridLengthAnimation));
        ToProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("To", typeof(GridLength), typeof(GridLengthAnimation));
    }

    public override Type TargetPropertyType {
        get { return typeof(GridLength); }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() {
        return new GridLengthAnimation();
    }

    public ContentElement Target { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty;
    public GridLength From {
        get { return (GridLength) GetValue(FromProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FromProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty;
    public GridLength To {
        get { return (GridLength) GetValue(ToProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToProperty, value); }
    }

    public void BeginAnimation() {
        Target.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, null);
        Target.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, this);
    }

    public IEasingFunction EasingFunction { get; set; } = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };

    public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue, object defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock) {
        double fromValue = ((GridLength) GetValue(FromProperty)).Value;
        double toValue = ((GridLength) GetValue(ToProperty)).Value;
        double newValue = 0;

        if ((fromValue > toValue)) {
            newValue = (1 - EasingFunction.Ease(animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value)) * (fromValue - toValue) + toValue;
            return new GridLength(newValue, GridUnitType.Star);
        } else {
            newValue = EasingFunction.Ease(animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value) * (toValue - fromValue) + fromValue;
            return new GridLength(newValue, GridUnitType.Star);
        }
    }
}
```

To begin the animation, I do it this way in my `MainWindows.xaml.cs` file:

```
GridLengthAnimation gridAnim = new GridLengthAnimation() {
    Name = "gridAnim",
    Target = mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1],
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
};

gridAnim.From = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
gridAnim.To = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);

gridAnim.BeginAnimation();
```

Where could I remove the animation after it's completed?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but where and how do you set that animation?

Comment: @lokusking I edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493(v=vs.100).aspx), in the "*Remove an animation from an individual property*" part.

I added this in my `GridLengthAnimation`:

```
public void BeginAnimation() {
    Completed += GridLengthAnimation_Completed;
    Target.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, null);
    Target.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, this);
}

private void GridLengthAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //unlocks the property
    Target.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, null);

    //holds the value at the end
    ((ColumnDefinition) Target).Width = new GridLength(((GridLength) GetValue(ToProperty)).Value, GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your usage to:

```
    GridLengthAnimation gridAnim = new GridLengthAnimation() {
            Name = "gridAnim",
            Target = this.MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1],
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
          };

          gridAnim.From = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
          gridAnim.To = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);
//Cleanup on Complete
          gridAnim.Completed += (sender, args) => {
                                                    var xx = sender as AnimationClock;
                                                    (xx.Timeline as GridLengthAnimation).Target = null;
          };
          gridAnim.BeginAnimation();
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work... I think it's a good idea but the property is still locked. Maybe there's an other way?